# Incredibly strange JavaScript date issue

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, date

The code:

```
function format_date( date, index )
{
    if ( !date || ( index && !( date[ index ] ) ) )
    {
        return '';
    }

    console.log( date );

    var date = new Date(
        ( index === undefined ) ? date : date[ index ]
    );

    console.log( date );


    return ( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' +
        date.getDate() + '/' +
        date.getFullYear() + ' 12:00 AM'
    ;
};

format_date( "2013-07-25" );
```

Output:

```
2013-07-25
Date {Wed Jul 24 2013 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)}
"7/24/2013 12:00 AM"
```

This is on a node JS server running on Linux. The output from `date` is:

```
Fri Aug  2 10:39:28 EDT 2013
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Maybe you are confused because the date parsed on `new Date(...)` is considered GMT, while you are using `getDate()` instead of `getUTCDate()` when manually parsing?

Comment: hey you might be interested in the time/date library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to do this kind of stuff easily

Comment: @Plato That is an exceptionally cool library, but might be more than what I need.

Comment: This is just one of many things screwy with JS `Date`.  Moment.js will make your life *much* easier.  Even if you only use pieces of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify a timezone offset, it assumes that your date is in GMT time.

Comment: True, but only because the string is entered with dashes as separators.  If it was provided as "2013/07/25" instead, then it would be interpreted as local time.  All the better to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)